# Recurrence relation for the number of partitions of an integer $n$ with distinct summands

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Let $Q(n)$ give the number of ways of writing the integer $n$ as a sum of positive integers without regard to order with the constraint that all integers in a given partition are distinct. Equation $(11)$ on [this page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html) mentions (without proof) a recurrence relation for $Q(n)$,

$$Q(n) = s(n) + 2\sum_{i=1}^\sqrt{n}(-1)^{k+1}Q(n-k^2)$$

where

$$s(n) = \begin{cases}
    (-1)^j,& \text{if } n= j(3j \pm 1)/2\\
    0,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

What is the proof of this fact?

Comment: Also posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349812/recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-partitions-of-an-integer-with-distinct without notifying either site of the post to the other. Please don't do that, it's an abuse.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Apologies. This was my first post on MO. I had heard that MO was for research level math and there was no activity on this question here. Further, this seemed to fit the guidelines on MO. I was not aware of the protocol for migrating a question and so I posted it there.